# Unexpected local path as part of Exception message from a remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, exception

We have our ASP.NET Web Forms project on a IIS server, with Entity Framework and the connection string correctly* pointing to our SQLServer on another machine. A couple of days ago I started to see local paths in the stack trace of a exception:

```
[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +11430407

   MyCompany.MyProject.Clases.CargaListados.CargaCategorias(DropDownList DdlCategorias) in c:\Users\myname\workspace\v5\MyWebSite\MyCompany.MyProject\Clases\CargaListados.cs:143
   MyCompany.MyProject.UserControls.Comunes.Buscadormicrotarea.CargaDesplegables() in c:\Users\myname\workspace\v5\MyWebSite\MyCompany.MyProject\UserControls\Comunes\Buscadormicrotarea.ascx.cs:58
```

Finally the exception was caused by the fact that the machine that stores the SQLServer was down...

But what bugs me is watching local paths in the trace.

I have a set of connection strings to work in local against a local DB. Then another connection strings to work via VPN against the SQLServer machine. And finally another set to put in the Web.config when the code is stored at the web server (to connect to the SQLServer machine). Everything works as of today, without having done any changes to the code or the connection strings.

Why am I seeing my local routes in the error?

*or that was my guess since it 'connects', but now I don't know.

Comment: Those local paths are from debugging symbols (.pdb) files which you probably deployed together with binaries to server.

Comment: Yes! I deployed the project using a fairly copy-paste troglodyte method. So I've found .pdb in the /bin /obj/Debug /obj/Release folders. I've deleted all of them and now the "c:\..." references are gone. Any other caveats I should be aware of because of the copy-paste? Thanks and please change your comment into an answer to let me mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code file names (and even line number of the specific statement) are included in stack trace because you deployed debugging symbols (.pdb) files together with your binaries. When stack trace is generated, .NET will look for those .pdb files and (if possible) will gather source code file and line number information from them and include into stack trace. So to prevent that - just don't deploy .pdb files. Also ensure that you deploy release version and not debug to production environment.

Comment: Luckily this is a pre-production machine. And they're sensible enough not to give me access to the production environment :)

Comment: Well local paths are not THAT sensible information to be honest :) Of course you don't want to throw such stacktraces to the public, but for internal use not much of a problem.